# Create an observation profile

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to create an observation profile example with this rule

```
* method.coding[0] = LNC#LP220279-6 "Photometric"
```

but I get this error when I try to generate FSH

```
The code "LP220279-6" is not valid in the system http://loinc.org; The code provided (http://loinc.org#LP220279-6) is not valid in the value set 'All codes known to the system' (from http://tx.fhir.org/r4) for 'http://loinc.org#LP220279-6'
```

Comment: I did a search on loinc.org and couldn't find it.  Are you sure it's a valid code?  Can you share a link to where it appears on loinc.org?

Comment: https://loinc.org/LP220279-6/, that's the one